# Is there a latin word for 'plausible deniability'?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, word-request, word-comparison, word-choice, english

Plausible deniability in English is **a condition in which a subject can safely and believably deny knowledge of any particular truth that may exist so as to shield the subject from any responsibility associated with the knowledge of such truth**.

Is there a word or phrase in Latin that would adequately convey this meaning? Ideally it should be a single word.

Comment: For those who are attempting to answer this question, there is a term _veri similis_ which means probable or plausable. In addition, I personally did not find any word directly meaning "deniability," so I made one up based on _nego, negare, negavi, negatus_, which is _negabilitas_. Do with that what you will!

Comment: The Italian translation of the term is *negazione plausibile*, which makes me want to favor a simple *negatio credibilis / veri similis*

Comment: @brianpck My vote would definitely be for *negatio probabilis / credibilis*.

Comment: Though thinking about it now, the former might mean "a denial is likely [forthcoming]."

Comment: When was the concept coined?

Comment: @Rafael It seems to derive from [John Dulles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plausible_deniability#History) and the CIA (which is consistent with my understanding of the history of term.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The term is rather new, so there is very low probability for an established Latin translation.
Therefore I will coin a new one.

There are a number of words one could use to translate "to deny".
One is *negare*, but perhaps *abiurare*, "to deny any thing on oath", is a better fit in the present case.
As [a corpus search](http://latin.packhum.org/search?q=abiur) shows, it can be used transitively.
Therefore something that can be denied on oath can be called *abiurabilis*, and the corresponding deniability is *abiurabilitas*.

Then it comes to finding a translation for "plausible".
Pitkäranta's dictionary suggests *probabilis*, *credibilis*, *fide dignus*, and *veri similis*.
The last option sounds a little off in this context, and judging by the entries for [*probabilis*](http://latinlexicon.org/definition.php?p1=2047746), [*credibilis*](http://latinlexicon.org/definition.php?p1=2014368), and [*fides*](http://latinlexicon.org/definition.php?p1=2022304) leads me to think that *fide dignus* is the most appropriate choice here.
It might be translated as "deserving of belief", and that is what "plausible" is all about in this phrase.

Putting these together, my suggestion is ***abiurabilitas fide digna***.

However, if you want a single word, then I recommend ***abiurabilitas***, "deniability on oath".
I don't see how to add plausibility to the picture without adding a word.
If three words is too much, I suggest *abiurabilitas probabilis*.

Comment: Thank you! (Sorry for the late response, I had stopped checking for answers.)

Comment: @Awn No problem! It was a late answer, and there was no hurry. I'm glad to be able to help.